# ASP Gridview change header in templateField

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, rendering

I whant to set a Checkbox (that is positioned in the Header of my Gridview) checked in some cases in my Codebehind. Here you can see my Templatefield

```
  <asp:GridView ID="MyGridView" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" DataSourceID="DataSource1" AllowSorting="True"
                AllowPaging="true" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" UseAccessibleHeader="True" ViewStateMode="Enabled"
                OnSorting="onSort" EmptyDataText="Keine Daten gefunden! Setzen Sie die Filter zurück und versuchen Sie es erneut.">
  <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
```

...

```
  <asp:TemplateField>
      <ItemTemplate>
          <asp:CheckBox runat="server" Checked='<%# Eval("SomeData")%>' Enabled="false" />
       </ItemTemplate>
       <HeaderTemplate>
          <asp:LinkButton runat="server" Text="NÜ" CommandName="Sort" CommandArgument="SomeData" ForeColor="White" ToolTip="SomeData"></asp:LinkButton>
          <br />
          <asp:CheckBox ID="checkSearchSomeData" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="onFilter"/>                                
       </HeaderTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
```

I have tryed it the way shown here:

```
    Dim tc As TableCell = MyGridView.HeaderRow.Cells(2)
    For Each c As Control In tc.Controls
        If c.GetType.Equals((New CheckBox).GetType) Then
            Dim cb2 As CheckBox = c
            cb2.Checked = True
            cb2.DataBind()
            tc.DataBind()
            MyGridView.DataBind()
        End If
    Next
```

and I also tryed that way:

```
    Dim cb As CheckBox = MyGridView.HeaderRow.FindControl("checkSearchSomeData")
    cb.Checked = True
    cb.DataBind()
```

but in my Gridview there is no Checkbox checked. I think it has something to do with the Rendering.

Can anyone help? Thanks! Of course I am also happy for examples changing something else then a Checkbox!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found some solution. It works using a session variable for the checked Signal see here:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtSearchVorname" runat="server" Text='<%# Session("Test") %>' AutoPostBack="true" OnTextChanged="onFilter" CssClass="grid_tb"></asp:TextBox>
```

of course you cal also use a Checkbox and the checked sign instead!